# The from address is being ignored spring mailer

Tags: spring-boot

> I don't know why the from address is being ignored and it is set to
> to@gmail.com

```
@Service
    public class EmailSenderService {
        @Autowired
        private JavaMailSender mailSender;
    
        public void sendEmail(String fromEmail,String toEmail, String subject, String body){
            SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
            message.setFrom(fromEmail);
            message.setTo(toEmail);
            message.setText(body);
            message.setSubject(subject);
    
            mailSender.send(message);
            System.out.println("Mail sent successfully...");
        }
    }
```

> I send mail using SimpleMailMessage. Everything is working nicely. But
> I don't know why on the receiver side shows spring.mail.username's
> address and not the From Adress. Each mail sent to the right address
> but from the address mail which is created in property
> spring.mail.username What method will use for this?

```
 @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
        public void sendMail() {
            senderService.sendEmail("from@yahoo.com",
                    "to@gmail.com",
                    "this is the subject",
                    "this is the body");
        }
```

> #Spring mailer properties

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=to@gmail.com
spring.mail.password=vryzdntajjbllkdt
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
```

Answer (score 0):

In `application.properties` file, you need to pass host, port, username and password of **From mail id**. There is no meaning in providing credentials of To_Address in application. Authentication is required for a sender. Hope it helped.